# add html signature to email mime message

Tags: email, mime

i have a postfix mail server.

i want to add an html signature for every outgoing email meesage

i have managed to configure postfix to use content filter and i can read the message before it have been sent.

i took the message and appended the following to the end:

```
--=_Part_2520f4165864eb419312d79028b30761_

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">=0A<html><bo=
dy style=3D3D'font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'><br /><br /><br /> <=
hr /><b>Please note</b> -  The message sent to you by unique users.<br /></body></html>
--=_Part_7860a1eebb3bd5833e91412077e2bf01_---
```

when i receive the message in gmail, yahoo or any other account the text does not show although that when looking at the message "original" i can see my signature at the footer.

one thing i can think of is that i may need to update the boundary to the message header